# Enquiry about printing the first 9 objects of a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I need to create a function that from given data, it determines the number of monitoring stations by a specific river. This function then needs to return the first N objects in the list of (*river name, number of stations*) tuples which are sorted in descending order of the number of stations.

However, some rivers may have the same number of stations, and these need to be considered as one entry in the list that is returned but I am unsure how I can do this. (The returned list may have more than N objects but only N numbers... if that makes sense)

The function I have created so far is the following:

```
def rivers_by_station_number(stations, N):

    riv_names = set()
    for station in stations:
        riv_names.add(station.river)

    num_stations = []
    for name in riv_names:
        n = 0
        for station in stations:
            if station.river == name:
                n += 1
            else:
                pass

        num_stations.append(n)

    lst_tuple = list(zip(riv_names, num_stations))
    lst_tuple_sort = sorted(lst_tuple, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    return lst_tuple_sort[:N]
```

Is there a sort function where I can return the first N objects of a sorted list whilst considering the same numbers as a singular entry?

**Extra Information**

When I run the function, where N = 9, I get the following results:

```
[('River Thames', 55), ('River Avon', 32), ('River Great Ouse', 30), ('River Derwent', 25), ('River Aire', 24), ('River Calder', 22), ('River Severn', 21), ('River Stour', 19), ('River Ouse', 18)]
```

So luckily for me, none of the rivers in the first 9 objects in the sorted list have the same number of monitoring stations, however, I would still like the implement the above in my function as data always changes.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: So you mean return 10 stations if there is a tie between two of the first nine?

Comment: @tripleee yes! sorry if I didn't make that too clear in my descriptions hahaha not very good at this

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function that does what you are asking (that I'm aware of), so the best approach seems to be essentially what you are doing, grouping the rivers by number of stations, sorting by number of stations, then taking the first `N` from that sorted list.

I would also break your code into two separate functions: one that takes in a list of stations and collects them by river name, and a second which takes those ( river name, station count ) pairs, and pulls out the first `N` of them.

#### Function to collect stations by river

The only way to really do this is loop through all the stations and collect them.

```py
from collections import Counter

def collect_stations( stations ):
    """
    :param stations: List of station objects.
    :returns: Dictionary like object of name-station count pairs.
    """
    river_count = {}
    names = [ s.river for s in stations ]
    return Counter( names )
```

#### Function which returns the first `N` stations

Here is a version that is a bit more compact

```py
def highest_counts( river_stations, N, flatten = True ):
    """
    :param river_stations: Dictionary like object of name-count pairs.
    :param N: Number of count groups to return.
    :param flatten: Flatten list of rivers.
    :returns: If flatten is True returns a list of ( name, count ) tuples of N unique counts. i.e. Rivers with the same number of counts are treated as one element. If flatten is False, a dictionary of { count: [ ( name, count ) ] is returned, with N count keys.
    """
    # group rivers by number of stations
    grouped = {}
    for name, count in river_stations.items():
        if count not in grouped:
            # add number group if it doesn't exist
            grouped[ count ] = []
            
        grouped[ count ].append( ( name, count ) )
        
    # sort groups by number of stations
    grouped = [ ( c, l ) for c, l in grouped.items() ]
    grouped.sort( key = lambda x: x[ 0 ], reverse = True )
    
    # get first N number groups
    stats = grouped[ :N ]

    if flatten:
        stats = [ 
            river 
            for num_list in stats
            for river in num_list[ 1 ]
        ]

    return stats
```

Another approach would be to sort the initial list, then take elements until `N` stations numbers have been seen.

```py
from collections import Counter

def highest_counts( river_stations, N ):
    """
    :param river_stations: Dictionary like object of name-count pairs.
    :param N: Number of count groups to return.
    :returns: List of ( name, count ) tuples of N unique counts. i.e. Rivers with the same number of counts are treated as one element.
    """
    # sorts by number of stations
    river_stations_list = [ ( name, count ) for name, count in river_stations.items() ]
    s = sorted( river_stations_list, key = lambda x: x[ 1 ], reverse = True )
    
    # gets number of stations for each element
    nums = [ x[ 1 ] for x in s ]
    
    # calculates how many indices incorporate first N number groups
    freqs = list( Counter( nums ).values() )
    ind = sum( freqs[ :N ] )
    
    # return first elements that incorporate N number groups
    return s[ :ind ]
```

Doing a quick performance check, the second version becomes much faster for larger inputs.
[image: Timing ratio of versions for differing input sizes.]

#### Final function

Your final function would then combine the two above.

```py
def rivers_by_station_number( stations, N ):
    """
    :param stations: List of station objects.
    :param N: Number of count groups to return.
    :returns: List of ( name, count ) tuples of N unique counts. i.e. Rivers with the same number of counts are treated as one element.
    """
    collected = collect_stations( stations ):
    return highest_counts( collected, N )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't efficient, firstly I will optimize it:

```
def rivers_by_station_number(stations, N):

    river_station = {}
    for station in stations:
        river_station[station.river] = river_station.get(station.river, 0) + 1


    sorted_river_station = sorted(river_station.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
    
 
    length = len(sorted_river_station)
    if N>= length: return sorted_river_station
    min_station_count = sorted_river_station[N-1][1]
    while N<length and  sorted_river_station[n] == min_station_count:
        N+=1
    return sorted_river_station[:N]
```

What I do is, I find the N-th river's station count and iterate from that river till the end while checking if the remaining rivers have the same amount of station.

Comment: The author of the question states that `... considering the same numbers as a singular entry?` however it appears your code only accounts for ties in the last position, but not in intermediary positions. It seems that the author wants ties in all positions to be disregarded towards the final count of returned elements, though.

Comment: @bicarlsen, it is not that clear from the text, I will update my code